# Estimation of the integral

Tags: integration, normed-spaces, estimation

I am trying to compute, or find a good estimate from above the following integral
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|t|^{-1/p}\left|\frac{|t|^{\nu}-1}{t-1}\right|dt,
$$where $0<1/p<1$ and $1/p-1<\nu<1/p$.

Thank you.

Comment: You could probably tidy up the notation and expression a bit: I politely suggest you find a new name for $1/p$ and ignore the factor $1/\pi$.

Can you bound the fraction in the integrand, near $1$, and can you show that its growth at $\pm\infty$ is killed by the other multiplicative factor? Then I'd say you're done, via some sort of Hölder's inequality argument.

Comment: My second pair of suggestions is actually rubbish, sorry.

Comment: Start by dividing **R** into four sub-intervals.

Comment: Then use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the following somewhat messy estimates. First define $r=1/p$, so that $-1<r-1<\nu<r<1$. Then notice that the potentially problematic points are $-\infty,0,1$ and $+\infty$. We consider $1$ first:

Let $|t-1|<1/2$. Then by Taylor's theorem and the triangle inequality, for some $\tau$ between $1$ and $t$,
$$\left|\frac{|t|^\nu-1}{t-1}\right|\leq|\nu|\left(1+\frac{1-\nu}{2}|\tau-1|\right)<2.$$
Now look at $0$. If $|t|<1/2$ then (simply picture the graphs of the denominator and numerator)
$$\left|\frac{|t|^\nu-1}{t-1}\right|\leq\frac{1-|t|^\nu}{1-|t|}<2,$$
and furthermore
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|t|^{-r}\text dt=2^r/(1-r)\leq2/(1-r).$$
Finally, note $-1-r+\nu<-1$ and that the integrand equals
$$|t|^{-1-r+\nu}\left|\frac{1-|t|^{-\nu}}{1-t^{-1}}\right|.$$
Consider the fraction in this product. By repeated use of the triangle inequality, if $-1<t<-1/2$ this is bounded by $(2^\nu-1)/2<2$, if $t<-1$ it is bounded by $1$, and if $t>3/2$ it is bounded by $3$. Choose the uniform bound $3$ in all cases. Then
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|t|^{-r}\big||t|^\nu-1\big||t-1|^{-1}\text dt\leq3 +\frac{4}{1-r}+6\int_{1/2}^\infty|t|^{-1-r+\nu}\text dt.$$
I'll leave the final steps to you. Is this sufficient? Would you like me to offer more details?

(I should note I'm more of an asymptotic analyst; a hard analyst will almost certainly be able to find sharper estimates than my rough bounds.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Stromael, Yes, please, I would like to see the details.

Comment: What details are missing, specifically?